# Android Studio 3.0 Error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, refresh, android-studio-3.0

I had updated my android studio to version 3.0 and when I tried to build an existing code which works fine in previous version of android studio shows below error.

```
Error:Could not download compiler.jar (com.android.databinding:compiler:2.3.0): No cached version available for offline mode
```

My grade version is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
```

Please help me...

Comment: It seems that you are offline: No cached version available for offline mode. Just check your internet connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disable** Offline Mode.

Go to **File > Settings > type gradle in search > select Gradle under Build Tools > uncheck `Offline work`**

Also, make sure that your **internet connection** is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

It really seems that you are offline, theres a option on the settings tab for supporting offline mode, it's probably checked, uncheck the box and try again

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same issue solved by using

```
  buildscript {
   repositories {
    ...
       // You need to add the following repository to download the
    // new plugin.
    google()
  }

   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
  }
 }
```

and then goto Build>cleanproject then all worked fine in my side 
 for more info check https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#update_gradle